# Why Angular's mat-select does not choose and open on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, sass, angular-material, tailwind-css

I created a form that includes a mat-select too. It works on web, and also toogle device toolbar too. But when I publish it on the server, mat-select is not showing, choosing, or opening. How can i fix this problem? I tried style='display: inline-block !important' but it is not working. This is my code.

```
<!-- Department field -->
<mat-form-field class="w-full">
    <mat-label>Fakülte</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControlName]="'department'" [(ngModel)]="selectedDep">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of departments" [value]="dep.id">{{dep.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I create a styleUrls and implement this:
.my-class {
    display: block !important;
}
but it still does not work.